# Android virtual device appears rotated in portrait mode

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I ran into very weird problem with Android virtual devices - I'm trying to create a new VD for APIs 11 or 12, but every time I run them - they appear rotated 90 degrees in portrait mode:

[image]

if I'm trying to rotate it with NumPad 7 or Ctrl+F11 then this is what I get:

[image]

Had anybody experienced this problem? What is the reason and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure about it as you are working on APIs 11 or 12 but this is a known problem reported by a lot of people for  KitKat AVD(see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61671).

Maybe this is the same kind of bug that is causing problems in APIs 11 or 12.

Comment: I'm not sure that is it, as the issue in the addressed topic is orientation change in AVD with API 19, while in my case I can change the orientation, but in portrait mode it appears rotated 90 degrees.

Comment: @Igal In potrait mode it is going landscape (see https://android.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=616710012000&name=Screenshot+-+Tuesday+17+December+2013+-+04%3A55%3A31++IST.png&token=ABZ6GAelR_LrzWpK3rp_pX6Nlk3pT7KCdQ%3A1408346097317&inline=1) .Maybe this is not the same problem but it could be due to some bugs.